# Figuring out whether the user inputs a numeric value or something else?

Tags: java

Used language is Java.

So I'm in a situation where my code expects a numeric input from the user(standard input)
I need to know whether they entered a number or anything else. I tried:

```
Scanner std = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
String userIn = std.nextLine();

int userInLength = userIn.length();

char[] input = new char[userInLength];

for (int i = 0; i < userInLength; i++) {
    input[i] = userIn.charAt(i);
}

for (char s : input) {
    String temp = String.valueOf(s);
    if (
            ! ( temp.equals("0") || temp.equals("1") || temp.equals("2") || temp.equals("3") ||
            temp.equals("4") || temp.equals("5") || temp.equals("6") || temp.equals("7") ||
            temp.equals("8") || temp.equals("9") )
    ) {
        System.out.println(s + " is not a number. Please enter numbers only.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(s + " is a numbers");
    }
}
```

I believe such a code could've been better.. Also, it works for 0-9 only. I need a way that includes any sort of number(e.g. 0.33, -22.8)
Any APIs or thoughts?

Comment: `if (userIn.matches("[-+]?(\\d+)?(\\.(\\d+)?((?i)E\\d+)?)?")) { System.out.println(userIn + " is a numerical value."); } else { System.out.println(userIn + " is not a numerical value."); }`. Handles numerical values like: `"05"`, `"0"`, `"18"`, `"-12"`, `"-33.0"`, `"0.33"`, `"-22.8"`, `".675E8"`, `"-.322"`, `"44.343e6"`, `"+453"`, `"+94.234"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does that ::

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n;
        try{
            n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            System.out.println("The number entered is : " + n);
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println("Input is not a number!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you use long use : `Long.parseLong(reader.readLine())`

If you use double use : `Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine())`

If you use float use : `Float.parseFloat(reader.readLine())`

Comment: Thank you. I'll use the Double.parseDouble(); only.. Since double happily excepts any other numeric value.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function that uses Regular Expression to check if the values are a valid number

```java
class Main {
  public static boolean isNumberValue(String value) {
    boolean isNum = value.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
    return isNum;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isNumberValue("3.5")); // true
    System.out.println(isNumberValue("35")); // true
    System.out.println(isNumberValue("Hello")); // false
  }
}
```

Comment: I still don't know much about RegEx stuff! This comment triggers me to dive in it! Thank you, I'll try to study and analyze this answer.

Comment: This can be shortened to "`^\d$`"